# BufferedReader returning columns instead of row

Tags: java, bufferedreader

When I do this...

```java
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] data = line.split(",");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I print `data[0]`, I get the first column instead of the first row. How can I modify it to return rows when I do `data[0]`?

When I did...

```
List<String> data;

try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    data = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And do `data.get(0)`, I get rows as expected, so why not with the first method?

Comment: What do you think, will `line.split(",")` do?

Comment: So I assume, in each line, you have a row?

Comment: A `line` is a row. Your variable name already reflects what you have. Then, you tell it to `split` the line at the commas and take the first element of the result. And then, you are surprised that this is a “column”. Why do you split the line when you do not want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you read each line with `bufferedReader.readLine()`, which already gives you a row. Then you split the row at the `,` char, which gives you columns for the current row.

Your seconds example, using `bufferedReader.lines()` returns a Stream of rows, which you collect with `.collect(Collectors.toList())`. Each of that rows in your List still simply has a string with all the commas in it. So what you probably want is a 2D-Array or a `List<List<String>>`.

You can achieve this as follows:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    final List<List<String>> table = br.lines()
            .map(row -> Stream.of(row.split(","))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(table.get(0));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] data = line.split(",");
}
```

In here you're fetching a single line, spliting it into parts by `,` and assigning to the `data` variable. At that time you have a single line processed, there is no way to refer row x as you only got one row. And that variable is defined inside of the while loop so it's state is only accessible during one given iteration.

Comment: Your second snippet returns a list of rows, whats the problem? Doing the same with an array would be impractical as you would need to know how many rows there are before starting reading the data.

Answer (score 1):

In a CSV file, each *line* is a row. Splitting the lines is what gives you the columns. So if you want the rows, you do not need to split the lines, just print them out the way they are. For example to print out just the first row, all you need to do is

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    String firstRow = bufferedReader.readLine();
    System.out.println(firstRow);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @levivah940 you should start deciding, what you actually want. Then, write your actual goal into your question. You have already shown code to get a `List` of all lines. When you want an array instead, change it to `bufferedReader.lines().toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: This still gives you a complete line, but with the separators in it. If that's what he want's okay, but would rather split the row and transform it into a List or Array of columns as well.